# Node js - Request Error transaction was deadlocked

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm having problems when i insert several data using promise, sometimes it works but other times give me this error:

[image]

And my code is this:

```
return Promise.all([
    Promise.all(createBistamp),
    Promise.all(createSlstamp),
    listOfResults,
    i
  ]).then(function(listOfResults2) {
    for(var j=0; j<resultArticle.length; j++) {
      if(arm === 'Arm-1') {
      }
      if(arm === 'Arm-1-11') {
      }
    }
    if(arm === 'Arm-1') {
      console.log("PROMISE ARM-1");
      return Promise.all([insertBi,insertBi2,insertSl]).then(function (insertEnd) {
        res.send("true");
      }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
    }
    if(arm === 'Arm-1-11') {
      console.log("PROMISE ARM-1-11");
      return Promise.all([insertBi,insertBi2,insertSl,insertSlSaida]).then(function (insertEnd) {
        res.send("true");
      }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
    }
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

I remove the code line inside ifs and for but it was inserts in database.

Example of insert:

```
var insertBi2 = request.query("INSERT INTO bi2 (bi2stamp,alvstamp1,identificacao1,szzstamp1,zona1,bostamp,ousrinis,ousrdata,ousrhora,usrinis,usrdata,usrhora)"+
                "VALUES ('"+bistamp+"','AB16083056009,454383576','2','Adm13010764745,450449475','1','"+bostamp+"','WWW','"+data+"','"+time+"','WWW','"+data+"','"+time+"')");
```

**Full Code:**
http://pastebin.com/DTjtXvDt

This is my structure and i don't know if i'm working well with promises.

Thank you

Comment: Are you only trying to insert into a DB? Are you using a database-specific library? That should handle the promises for you.

Comment: What is `i`? Where are `insertBi`, `insertBi2`, `insertSl`, `insertSlSaida` defined?

Comment: i'm using mssql library @LuisDiegoHernández

Comment: Like i said i don't put this kind of information because it is much information to put into question. But i give you an example... @guest271314

Comment: Please quote the error message as text rather than a screenshot.

Comment: It's almost impossible to truly decipher the depths of the updates/inserts going on here, but at a glance it seems to me that some of these promises are, sometimes, firing in a manner that locks a database as another query arrives, but has a dependency on the other query, thus creating a deadlock. You might have to rethink the structure of your queries/promises to really get through this with a reliable structure.

Comment: I update the question inserting the full code link. @DavidW

Comment: Just to reiterate David's comment, rather than trying to solve for this issue as is, refactor it taking consideration for what can be async and what cannot be.. Not much help I know!

Comment: I put the full error! @jcaron

Comment: What database (driver) are you using? Please post more information about that (and tag your question appropriately)

Comment: Your queries seem to lack any escaping and are prone to SQL injections.

Comment: Still, but it as text, not a screenshot. It will be more readable and more searchable.

Comment: What is this code contained in, a function? And do you use any kind of transaction management with your database? Show that code as well, please.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are `createBistamp` and `createSlstamp` arrays?

Comment: Yes, they are! @guest271314

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced this problem recently.

```
error: RequestError: Transaction (Process ID 72) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

**Solution** - 
There was not a single index on the table. So, I created a non-clustered unique index on the unique identifier column. 
I was surprised when this solution worked

There was a single update operation in the code and no select operation. So, it made me curious to do some research. I came across `lock granularity` mechanism for locking resources. In my case, locking has to be at row level instead of page level.

**Note:** 
For clustered tables, the data pages are stored at the leaf level of the (clustered) index structure and are therefore locked with index key locks instead of row locks.

**Further Reading** 
https://www.sqlshack.com/locking-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

If you are inserting data or updating data in a loop, then it's better to make all queries in the loop and store it and then execute it all at once in a single transaction. Will save yourself with a lot of issues